# Issue with looping through index and sending email

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, wait

I have a python code that sends an email based on the value of a column. It iterates over each row in a data frame and checks if the column value is 1. Here the column is time flag. The issue is that I am not able to prevent it from sending multiple times, meaning to say that once the email is sent and if the while loop runs the second time, the for loop is executed and the email is sent again which I don't want.

Instead of this, I want to send an email only once for the row that has the time flag to be 1. The next email should be sent after one hour for that row. I thought of storing the index in a list for the rows where the time flag is 1 but unable to proceed after that.

```
def send_email(previousindex,index):

        print('entering if loop')
        fromaddr = "**********"
        toaddr = "*********"
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['From'] = fromaddr
        msg['To'] = toaddr
        a = str(df.loc[df.index[index], 'Station ID'])
        b = str(df.loc[df.index[index], 'Time Difference'])
        print(a)
        msg['Subject'] = "Timestamp Alarm for Station"+ " " + a + " "+"(No data since" +" "+b+")"
        df1 = df.iloc[index,:]

        #Adding styles to the html table
        with open('cssfile.txt', 'r') as myfile:
            style = myfile.read()
        #Mail body
        body = """<html><head></head>{1}<div>{0}</div></html>""".format(pd.DataFrame(df1).T.to_html(index=False),style)
        part = MIMEText(body,'html')
        msg.attach(part)
        server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.office365.com",587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login('*********', '**********')
        server.sendmail(fromaddr,toaddr,msg.as_string())
        server.quit()
    else:
        print('entering else loop')
        time.sleep(3600)


while True:
    previousindex = []
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
        'DRIVER=' + driver + ';SERVER=' + server + ';PORT=1433;DATABASE=' + database + ';UID=' + username + ';PWD=' + password)
    df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM source_reads', cnxn)
    df['current_time'] = datetime.datetime.now() - pd.DateOffset(hours=8)
    df['current_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['current_time'], infer_datetime_format=True)
    df['last_reported_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['last_reported_at'], infer_datetime_format=True)
    df['Current UTC Time'] = df['current_time'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M %p')
    df['local time'] = datetime.datetime.now()
    df['local time'] = df['local time'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M %p')
    df['TD'] = df['current_time'] - pd.to_datetime(df['last_reported_at'])
    TimeD = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['TD'])
    df['TimeD'] = TimeD.hour * 60 + TimeD.minute
    df['Time Difference'] = df['TimeD'].map(str) + " " "min(s)"
    df['timeflag'] = df['TimeD'].apply(lambda x: '1' if x >= 15 else '0')
    df['timeflag'] = df['timeflag'].astype(str).astype(int)

    df = df.drop(
        columns=['created_at', 'updated_at', 'source_read_id', 'current_time', 'TimeD', 'TD', 'Current UTC Time'])

    condlist = [df['reporting_station_id'] == 1,
                df['reporting_station_id'] == 2,
                df['reporting_station_id'] == 3,
                df['reporting_station_id'] == 4,
                df['reporting_station_id'] == 5,
                df['reporting_station_id'] == 6,
                df['reporting_station_id'] == 7,
                df['reporting_station_id'] == 8,
                df['reporting_station_id'] == 9,
                df['reporting_station_id'] == 10,
                df['reporting_station_id'] == 11,
                df['reporting_station_id'] == 12,
                df['reporting_station_id'] == 13,
                df['reporting_station_id'] == 14,
                df['reporting_station_id'] == 15,
                df['reporting_station_id'] == 16,
                ]
    choicelist = [712,713,714,715,716,717,718,719,720,721,722,723,725,728,729]
    df['Station_id'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist)

    df.columns = ['id', 'Last Reported (UTC)', 'Reporting Station Id',
                  'Local Time', 'Time Difference', 'Time flag', 'Station ID', ]

    for index in df.index:  # row in df.iterrows():

        if df.loc[index, 'Time flag'] == 0:
            print('fail')
            print(previousindex)
            send_email(previousindex,index)
            l = previousindex.append(index)

        else:
            time.sleep(10)
            continue

    time.sleep(10)
```

**EDIT:** Getting an error when I subtract now and last email sent

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/KrishnamurthyKA/Desktop/Project/SQL.py", line 106, in <module>
    elif df.loc[index, 'Time flag'] == 1 and (now - df.loc[df.index[index],'emailsent_time'] > hour):
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'datetime.timedelta' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a column to the data frame with a timestamp that denotes when the last email was sent. Then when you're iterating over it, you can check whether it has been over an hour since you last sent an email, and if so you can send another email and save a new timestamp.

Pseudocode example:

```
import time
# initialize all 'email_sent_at' = 0

# time.time() returns seconds since epoch, and one hour is 60*60 seconds.
hour = 60*60

for row in dataframe:
    now = time.time()
    if row['time_flag'] == 1 and (now - row['email_sent_at'] > hour):
        send_email()
        # reset the timestamp, so that another 60*60 seconds need to pass
        # before another email is sent.
        row['email_sent_at'] = now
    else:
        # either the 'time_flag' is not set, or it is set and it's less
        # than an hour since the last sent email.
        pass
```

Comment: Can you share a dummy code for example? Thank you. @kreld

Comment: Hi @kreld, thank you for the pseudo code. I am getting an error when I subtract now with last email sent. Can you please help?
I have added the code in the edit.

Comment: Have you tried using time.time() as per the example, rather than datetime.timedelta? time.time() returns a float that you can directly compare to an integer.

Comment: It gives me the below error.
if df.loc[index,'Time flag'] == 1 and index['email_sent_time'] == 0:
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: I am really confused with handling variables and columns in a data frame. can you explain this please?

Comment: It looks to me like you have a variable called `index`, that is of type `int` and you're trying to address it like a list? Do you have an `'email_sent_time'` field in your data frame? If so, then you should probably address it as `df.loc[index, 'email_sent_time']`